# Can I specify file associations at a more general or specific level?

Tags: macos, file-extensions

Can I set Mavericks to do things like:

1. Open password-protected PDFs in a particular app (Skim), and other PDFs in another app, like Chrome or Preview?
2. Open all videos in VLC? Currently I have to do this again and again for each extension, like mov, m4v, avi, etc. When I double-click a video file, it's anybody's guess what app it opens in, depending on what the extension happens to be. Can I tell OS X to open all videos in VLC?
3. Building on (2), can I ask OS X to open all files that VLC can open, in VLC? This goes for both audio and video files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not certain about separating out password-protected PDFs specifically - it would depend on how they differentiated themselves to the OS, but everything else can be done with [RCDefaultApp](http://www.rubicode.com/Software/RCDefaultApp/)
which, though quite old, is still perfectly functional.
It adds itself as a control panel & can then adjust defaults for any app & protocol.